# Shutdown after inactivity

Tags: power-management, 21.10

Is possible to shutdown Ubuntu Desktop 21.10 after some time of inactivity ?
In settings is only option to auto suspend.

Regards

Comment: Everything is possible, but what to do with open files & applications? Data may be lost, files may be corrupted.

Comment: Jacob Vlijm is right. This it not a safe decision, but you can (always manually) set it from terminal with `shutdown [minutes before shutdown]`.

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/automatic-shutdown-hibernate-on-idle-ubuntu/

Search for `dconf editor` in Ubuntu Software or in GNOME Software, install, then open it.

Go to /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power

Scroll down to the bottom.

`sleep-inactive-battery-type` is for shutdown when on battery
and `sleep-inactive-ac-type` is for shutdown, when charging.
Set the value to *'shutdown'* for witch do you prefer.

E. G. if you want to only shutdown, when on battery, only set the `sleep-inactive-battery-type` to *'shutdown'*.

`sleep-inactive-battery-timeout` is the (shutdown) timeout when on battery in seconds, and obviously `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout` is for the timeout when charging.

After you made the changes click the check mark, close Dconf Editor, and now you're done!

Comment: @Octopus - it’s better as an answer anyway as the source isn’t from this site (thanks for contributing!). I’d encourage you to put the details in your answer rather than just a link - in case (for example) that site is removed at some point  in future.